# Firefox Three js texture rendering

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js

I am creating a plane in three js and apply a texture on it.
The texture is created with a canvas element.

For some reason Firefox seems to be the only browser having troubles with this, even IE11 works fine.

firefox example screenshot
[image: firefox example screenshot]

Chrome example screenshot
[image: Chrome example screenshot]

This is the code used.

```
//get text
    var text1 = container.getAttribute('data-text-1');
    var text2 = container.getAttribute('data-text-2');

    // //create image
    var bitmap = document.createElement('canvas');
    bitmap.width = 4000;
    bitmap.height = 1200;

    var ctx = bitmap.getContext('2d');

    ctx.strokeStyle="#fff";
    ctx.lineWidth = 200;
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,4000,1200);

    ctx.font = 'normal 300px proxima_novabold';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText(text1, 2000, 450);
    ctx.font = 'normal 240px proxima_novaregular';
    ctx.fillText(text2, 2000, 750);

    // canvas contents will be used for a texture
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(bitmap);
    texture.premultiplyAlpha = false;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    //plane
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000, 600, 80, 80),         
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide})
    );

    scene.add( plane );
```

Comment: Seems like the weird outline is the inverted color of the background element behind the canvas. But only for bright colors, dark colors don't show an outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add 'transparent: true' to the MeshBasicMaterial.